# cannot get lighttpd configured to web.py

Tags: python, lighttpd, web.py

I am trying to setup my web.py application with lighttpd server on ubuntu 14.04.

I have followed the following tutorials and did exactly the same what is mentioned.

http://crosbymichael.com/webpy-server-setup.html

and

https://superuser.com/questions/436580/setting-up-lighttpd-and-fastcgi-for-my-own-web-app

When i run the application i get the following error

> 2016-11-25 10:54:23: (log.c.166) server started  2016-11-25 10:54:23:
>   (mod_fastcgi.c.1103) the fastcgi-backend /var/www/index.py failed to
>   start:  2016-11-25 10:54:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1107) child exited with
>   status 13 /var/www/index.py  2016-11-25 10:54:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1110)
>   If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure
>   you're using the FastCGI-enabled version. If this is PHP on Gentoo,
>   add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.  2016-11-25 10:54:23:
>   (mod_fastcgi.c.1398) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.  2016-11-25
>   10:54:23: (server.c.1021) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that lighttpd tried and failed to start your app.  Try running your app manually to see why it does not start up.  It is possible that you are missing a Python modules needed by your script.

BTW, recent versions of lighttpd (1.4.42+) support WSGI for Python apps:

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSCGI

See also:

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI

Comment: so you mean if i host it in wsgi no need to run on lighttpd?

Comment: You still need lighttpd.  Check that your app is using the same protocol that you have configured lighttpd to use.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI

lighttpd executes your script from lighttpd's environment, which might be different from the environment when you execute it from the command line.  Check that lighttpd is using an appropriate PATH when attempting to start your script.

Comment: will you be able to help me? i could not figure still

Comment: Hint: start small.  Get one of the examples working from https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI before trying to get anything more complex working.